# Efficient DataTable in python flet

Tags: python, large-data, flet

I am developing a library management system in `python` with the help of `sqlite3` and `flet` modules. I have used the `DataTable` controls as follows:

```
class BooksStatusControl(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page

    def build(self):
        books = self.page.db.fetch_all_books()
        self.data_table = ft.DataTable(
            columns=[
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Id")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Title")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Author")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Issued to")),
            ],
            rows=[
                ft.DataRow(
                    cells=[
                        ft.DataCell(ft.Text(id)),
                        ft.DataCell(ft.Text(title)),
                        ft.DataCell(ft.Text(author)),
                        ft.DataCell(ft.Text(issued_to if issued_to is not None else "-")),
                    ],
                ) for id, title, author, issued_to in books
            ]
        )
        return ft.Container(
            height=500,
            content=ft.Column(
                scroll="always",
                controls=[
                    self.data_table
                ]
            )
        )
```

---

`self.page.db.fetch_all_books` implementation

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
    ...
    def fetch_all_books(self):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.file) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query = "SELECT * FROM BOOKS"
            cursor.execute(query)
            return cursor.fetchall()
```

It works fine when there are 10-15 books but starts lagging when there are near 200 books and does not even load at higher numbers. 
How can I make it efficient like the `ListView` control?

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant, then I did it like this

```
    self.list_view_table_cartridges = ft.ListView(expand=1, spacing=0, padding=0, auto_scroll=True)

    ##### --- Тавлица всех наименований картриджей
    self.table_cartridges = ft.DataTable(
        heading_row_color=colors.GREY_200,
        sort_ascending=True,
        columns=[
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("ID"), numeric=True),
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Наименование")),
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Действия")),
        ],
        # rows=[]
    )
self.list_view_table_cartridges.controls.append(self.table_cartridges)

for row in all_cartridges:
        self.table_cartridges.rows.append(
            DataRow(
                cells=[
                    DataCell(Row([
                        IconButton("ADD_OUTLINED", icon_color="green", data=row, tooltip="Добавить"),
                        Text(row['cartridg_id']),
                    ])),
                    DataCell(Text(row['cartridg_name'])),
                    DataCell(Row
                        ([
                            IconButton("create", icon_color="blue", data=row, tooltip="Редактировать"),
                            IconButton("delete", icon_color="red", data=row, tooltip="Удалить"),
                        ])
                    ),
                ]
            )
        )
return ft.View(
    "/cartridges_view/",
    controls=[
            self.list_view_table_cartridges,
    ]
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).